# xgettext dry run to avoid unnecessary commits in Github workflow

Tags: linux, github-actions, xgettext

Is there any way to do a dry run of `xgettext` on source files, in order to simply check if there are any differences compared to the current `.pot` file?

I have set up a Github workflow that will run `xgettext` on source files any time a change to a source file is pushed to the repository. The result is that often the change to the source file didn't change the translation strings, so the only difference in the resulting `.pot` file is the Creation date, which gets updated every time `xgettext` is run. This makes for unnecessary commits, and triggers unnecessary webhook calls to my weblate instance which picks up on an "updated" `.pot` file, and winds up generating its own Pull Request with an "updated" `.pot` file.

If there were a way to do a dry run and first check if there are any actual differences in the strings, I could avoid unnecessary commits and PRs from polluting my repo. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add a filter to my Github workflow, checking whether there are any significant changes besides a simple update to the value of `POT-Creation-Date` in the `.pot` file. I added an `id` to the step that takes care of running `xgettext`, then after running `xgettext` I save the count of significant lines changed in the pot file to a variable that will be accessible to the next step:

```yaml
      - name: Update source file translation strings
        id: update_pot
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install -y gettext
          xgettext --from-code=UTF-8 --add-comments='translators:' --keyword="pgettext:1c,2" -o i18n/litcal.pot index.php
          echo "::set-output name=POT_LINES_CHANGED::$(git diff -U0 | grep '^[+|-][^+|-]' | grep -Ev '^[+-]"POT-Creation-Date' | wc -l)"
```

Then I check against this variable before running the commit step:

```yaml
      - name: Push changes  # push the output folder to your repo
        if: ${{ steps.update_pot.outputs.POT_LINES_CHANGED > 0 }}
        uses: actions-x/commit@v4
        with:
          # The committer's email address
          email: 41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com
          # The committer's name
          name: github-actions
          # The commit message
          message: regenerated i18n/litcal.pot from source files
```

etc.